# Image Clip as a static resource in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, windows-phone-8, resources

Hi I want to display a rounded image and I am able to do like this:

```
<Image Style="{StaticResource RoundedImageStyle}" Source="MyImage.jpg">
    <Image.Clip>
        <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"/>
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

I am setting the style in a static resource like this

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>      
    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="RoundedImageStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Is there a way to Implement Image.Clip Property as a static resource too?

This is what I tried and it gives me the error: Value does not fall within expected range

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <EllipseGeometry x:Key="TitleImageClip" Center="50,50" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"/>    
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: That is indeed strange. I can confirm this problem, although I would have thought that it was possible to do because the `Image.Clip` property *is* a `DependencyProperty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't believe Clip is supported there. I verified that this has the
>   same behavior in Silverlight and in a Windows Store app on Windows 8.1
>   Preview.
>
> [Rob Caplan
>   [MSFT]](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/rob%20caplan%20%5Bmsft%5D/?ws=usercard-mini)

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f9cbb738-80a4-4e13-a4e8-b58b076780f0/how-to-set-image-clip-as-staticresource-style?forum=winappswithcsharp)